# Aws lambda function reruns itself evn if it is not failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate

I am running an AWS lambda function which is the endpoint of a load balancer.
This Lambda starts a Fargate instance and registers it in a newly created target group in the load balancer.

Here is the workflow :

- Start a fargate task instance
- Create a target group
- Create a listener rule for the load balancer
- Wait for the task to be running
- Registers the Fargate task as a target of the target group
- Wait for the task to be healthy and responding

It sometimes runs 2 or more Fargate instances, which is not necessary since the first one is already working.

I test this by pinging the Fargate with a https request and it is responding just fine, since it responds with a 200 status code, but inside the log the Lambda function re runs itself.

Here is the complete log of the lambda call:

```
    2022-07-01T15:23:48.623+02:00   START RequestId: 3a0c0b97-0a2b-444f-b1a3-89a98908826c Version: $LATEST
    2022-07-01T15:23:49.584+02:00   ID : b21e58a3738e472d94b5f94cf5aae7ea
    2022-07-01T15:23:57.401+02:00   Task attached !
    2022-07-01T15:24:10.230+02:00   Task running !
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.436+02:00   Target healthy !
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.729+02:00   response : b'{"message":"Flask server is running"}\n'
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.729+02:00   Task responded !
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.783+02:00   END RequestId: 3a0c0b97-0a2b-444f-b1a3-89a98908826c
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.783+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 3a0c0b97-0a2b-444f-b1a3-89a98908826c Duration: 35158.87 ms Billed Duration: 35159 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB Init Duration: 238.39 ms
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.832+02:00   START RequestId: 587f3c66-bd63-4608-8bef-d406fde84ef8 Version: $LATEST
    2022-07-01T15:24:23.881+02:00   ID : 4d7d6ca4570743f8838796bf8588b5b0
    2022-07-01T15:24:30.214+02:00   Task attached !
    2022-07-01T15:24:43.890+02:00   Task running !
    2022-07-01T15:24:56.448+02:00   Target healthy !
    2022-07-01T15:24:56.693+02:00   response : b'{"message":"Flask server is running"}\n'
    2022-07-01T15:24:56.693+02:00   Task responded !
    2022-07-01T15:24:56.761+02:00   END RequestId: 587f3c66-bd63-4608-8bef-d406fde84ef8
    2022-07-01T15:24:56.761+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 587f3c66-bd63-4608-8bef-d406fde84ef8 Duration: 32925.84 ms Billed Duration: 32926 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max M
```

Why does this Lambda rerun itself?

Comment: I am already returning a standardised  response as such : return {
            "statusCode":200,
            "statusDescription":"200 OK",
            "isBase64Encoded":False,
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"https://mydomain-name.com",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"OPTIONS,POST,GET"
            },
            "body": json.dumps({
                "data": data
            })
        }

Comment: The Lambda function is neither "re-running itself" nor is the Lambda service retrying it on error (in that case the request ID in both invocations would be the same). I believe that the Lambda function is being invoked twice. See this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-duplicate-invocations/) for more help.

Comment: Are you using provisioned concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it seems the problem was the preflight OPTION request that was trigerring the lambda. So I had to get the http method via the event and make a return for the OPTION request and do a 'else' for the other methods, simple as that...